# Pass credentials to karate .feature file from Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, karate, jenkins-groovy, cucumber-java, feature-file

Is there a way we can pass credentials from Jenkins to *.feature file while doing karate test? Please let me know how it can be done.